# Is there pmXor pen mode or similar mode for .NET system.drawing.pen?

Tags: .net, 2d, line, system.drawing, delphi-prism

I am programming in Delphi Prism. I am drawing line using mouse clicks as an input. I see that the lines are being drawn on my winform, but they are not being cleared as you move the mouse. It keeps drawing and eventually fills the winform adding lines for every mouse movement. I did try to invalidate the form or the region, but it causes my winform to flicker really bad. I know you can use pmXor pen mode on Delphi for win32. Are there similar pen mode for .NET? How do you make the lines disappear and only keep the active line on the form?

I searched Google, Stackoverflow and even MSDN library, there seems to be very little information on .NET penmode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ControlPaint has some DrawReversibleXxx methods.  Focus on getting rid of the flicker instead.  DoubleBuffered property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no xor pen mode in .net graphics.

Comment: @ David that explains why no one seems to be talking about it in relation to .NET. If it doesn't support xor mode, then what options are there if I may ask.

Comment: No options at all. No pen modes.